# How to build a c program project using meson

Tags: meson-build

I would like to build a c project using meson. Please provide the contents in meson.build file and where to place it?

These are the folders of the project

```
Project_dir/
        src/
          command.c
       include/
          command.h
       main.c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Project_dir/
            src/
              command.c
           include/
              command.h
           main.c
           meson.build
```

then in meson.build

```
        project(
          'dummy', 'c',
          version : '1.1.0',
          default_options : ['buildtype=debugoptimized','warning_level=1'],
        )
        
       #define default build args for all c
       build_args_c = ['-Wall',]
       #source cofe
       project_source_files = ['src/command.c','main.c',]  
       #include folder
       proj_headers = include_directories('include')
      
       executable(
              meson.project_name(),
              project_source_files,
              #dependencies:   [''],
              c_args : build_args_c,
              gnu_symbol_visibility : 'default',
              include_directories :  [proj_headers]
          )
```

then setup meson proj

```
meson setup dummyProj
```

then compile

```
meson compile -C dummyProj
```